# How to create a "template" to instantiate multiple times within a fragment/activity, filled with different data. Like Tweets

Tags: android

Kind of hard to explain what I'm going for. Basically, I'm working on the "Browse" function of my app, and you will be able to browse user posts. All the posts will have the same layout as you scroll through them, filled with different data (title, author, score, etc). I'm really not sure what the best way to approach this is. Creating views? Fragments?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the layout/ui you want to have. 
The obvious solution would be a `ListView` or a `ViewPager`.

Comment: So could I setup a gridlayout, then create a layout for the individual posts that has a class tied to it to get/set the data, then populate the grid with multiple instances of that post view?

Comment: the basic idea is that you have your data in some form (array, sql) and pass that to an adapter, which you feed to the ListView, which autogenerates each "block" with tha data provided and according to a predefined layout you provided. There are many tutorials to look at, for example: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html